# EF Core - mapping rows to a collection set

Tags: ef-core-2.2

I have the following tables:

Category

```
CategoryID | CategoryName
1          | Electronic
2          | Computer
3          | Monitor
4          | Laptop
```

SubCategory (category - subcategory relationship) table:

```
CategoryID | SubCategoryID
1          | 2
1          | 3
1          | 4
```

Both the above CategoryID and SubCategoryID columns in Subcategory table are key reference to CategoryID in the Category table.

question is: how do I do EF Core Map to the following classes?

```
public class Category
{
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public IList<Category> SubCategories { get;set; }
}
```

Comment: You are explaining it wrongly here: `Both the above CategoryID and SubCategoryID columns are FK to CategoryID in the Category table.` Please correct it.

Comment: they are indeed FK to category table.. not sure what you mean by "wrongly"